# date_range generator last 30 days Python

Tags: python

I would like to return a list of the last 30 days. This is what I've tried so far, but not sure how to proceed with returning the list

```
def date_range():
    start_date = datetime.date(2021,3,1)
    end_date = datetime.date(2021,3,31)
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    
    while start_date <= end_date:
        start_date+=delta
```

Desired output

```
date_range = ['2021-03-01','2021-03-02','2021-03-03','2021-03-04','2021-03-05',...]
```

Comment: Either you want to make a list and `append` each `start_date` to it and then return that list; or you indeed want to make this a *generator* and `yield` each `start_date`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an empty list and keep appending the dates:

```
import datetime


def date_range():
    result = []

    current = datetime.date(2021, 3, 1)
    end = datetime.date(2021, 3, 31)
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    while current <= end:
        result.append(current)
        current += delta

    return result

print(date_range())
```

Of course, you can pass start and end as parameters, which makes much more sense:

```
import datetime


def date_range(start, end):
    result = []

    current = start
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    while current <= end:
        result.append(current)
        current += delta

    return result


print(date_range(datetime.date(2021, 3, 1), datetime.date(2021, 3, 31)))
```

If you want them as strings:

```
import datetime


def date_range(start, end):
    result = []

    current = start
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    while current <= end:
        result.append(current.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
        current += delta

    return result


print(date_range(datetime.date(2021, 3, 1), datetime.date(2021, 3, 31)))
```

If you only need to iterate over them, you can yield them all and there is no need to create a list:

```
def date_range(start, end):
    current = start
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    while current <= end:
        yield current
        current += delta


for date in date_range(datetime.date(2021, 3, 1), datetime.date(2021, 3, 31)):
    print(date)
```

Comment: I would like to just return the list without the datetime.date in the beginning

Comment: what do you mean? as strings?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
import datetime

def date_range():
    end_date = datetime.date(2021, 3, 31)
    no_of_days = 30
    dates = []
    for i in range(no_of_days + 1):
        date = end_date + datetime.timedelta(days=-i)
        dates.append(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

    return dates
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will work

```
import datetime

base = datetime.date(2021,4,1)
rng = 30
date_list = []
for x in range(rng):
    date_lst = base + datetime.timedelta(days=x)
    date_lst = str(date_lst)
    date_list.append(date_lst)

print(date_list)
```

Comment: You should really work on that naming. `date_lst` is extremely confusing.